# create ssh-compatible vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I often run scripts on remote machines and sometimes create custom html dashboards to monitor progress. I was wondering if something like that would be better done taking advantage of vscode's ssh extension, which I use to edit files remotely anyway.

For example, I'd like to display a custom panel with information derived from a list of files in the remote server. My traditional approach would be to run a web server to get the file contents in some custom json format and create a custom html client to display the data. Would it be possible to skip the web server part and instead create some custom vscode extension that gets the data via some ssh api?

Answer (score 0):

It might be your case to use LogTail extension to fetch your data and then proceed with your desired display method.

VSCode Marketplace for LogTail: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tiansin.logtail

I hope it helps :)